# R - Only allow numbers and dots in column

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with lines looking like this

```
201712.20_16:26:;1.665855 1.28 2.00 0>86 271 327.4
```

These are logged and sometimes there are random letters, numbers or other characters in between the regular numbers and dates. If everything runs fine, it should look like this:

```
2017.12.20_11:19:58.132207 0.86 0.31 0.46 1.97 290.0
```

Is there a way to remove all lines not following the wanted "pattern"? Maybe something that restrics the columns (apart from the the date column) to digits between 0 and 9 and dots? And delete all lines where that is not the case?

I tried something like this:

```
numbers_only <- function(x) !grepl("^0-9.", x)
numbers_only(df$column)
```

But that doesn't seem to work, as I get TRUE even if there is a letter or some other specific sign in there. 
Same would go for the date column, just with numbers, dots, underscores and colons.

Comment: See if `grep("[^[:digit:][:space:]:_.]", x)` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following is what you need.

```
y <- c(
  "201712.20_16:26:;1.665855 1.28 2.00 0>86 271 327.4",
  "2017.12.20_11:19:58.132207 0.86 0.31 0.46 1.97 290.0"
)


numbers_only <- function(x) !grepl("[^[:digit:][:space:]:_.]", x)

numbers_only(y)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Even with alnum instead of digit. Thanks alot!

Comment: @BallerNacken You say to allow only numbers and dot, with `alnum` alphabetic characters will also be valid.

Comment: Okay changed it. Thx!